# Connection between two desktop applications

Tags: c#, connection

I'm working on finance related application that has two main functions:

1. Fetch market data from api and save to database
2. Analyse data and make decisions

Right now I have both functions inside one console application. I want to separate this to two independent applications. First application that fetch data should besides that, send fetched data to second application. I checked various solutions but I'm not sure which would be the best fit for app like that. I need reliability, almost instant speed (both run on same computer).

Options I found:

- SignalR
- Pipelines
- REST Api (probably the worst)

Comment: _which would be the best_ so, are you looking for opinions? This is an offtopic on SO.

Comment: Why do you want to separate in the first place?

Comment: I want to separate because fetching market should run 24/7, in data analysis I'm adding/changing methods, parameters. If I want to change something now I need to stop an application and so stops data fetching.

Comment: Since both run on the same machine and you need perfomance, option 1 and 3 are not good (especially 3). Look at some interprocess communication technique, like named pipes.